# How can I send custom email when user order a subscription in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I would like to know if there is some way to send a custom email to a user when he makes a (first) payment in Woocommerce. (I am using Woocommerce Subscriptions).

This email is about instructions to learn how to set up an account on the website. So I think, maybe there's a problem. If the email is sent to an user each time there's a payment, then, when the subscription is renewed, I think they are going to receive the same email of the instructions.

The intention is this email with the instructions would only be sent to users for the first payment.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we can send a custom mail for first time. you can use

- woocommerce_order_status_processing
- woocommerce_order_status_completed

when user complete subscription, your order shows as processing we can use ***woocommerce_order_status_processing*** hook or is it shows as completed we can use ***woocommerce_order_status_completed*** hook.
you can change order status in woocommerce subscription plugin

```
//code goes to function.php you can generate child theme and cop

add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'nazcloak_order_complete_actions', 10, 1);

function nazcloak_order_complete_actions($order_id)
{
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $user_id = $order->get_user_id();
    $args = array(
        'customer_id' => $user_id,
        'limit' => 2, // if you set -1 it'll retrive all orders
    );
    $orders = wc_get_orders($args);
    if( !empty($orders) && count($orders) < 2 )
    {
        $to = $order->get_billing_email(); //to get user email
        $first_name = $order->get_billing_first_name();
        $subject = 'Thank You for Subscription!';
        $message = "Hello $first_name, your message.";

        wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message ); //send email using
    }
}
```

to change from email

```
add_filter("wp_mail_from",  function($from){
 return "from@domain.com";
});
```

Comment: This works! Thank you so much! Do you know how can I change wordpress@email.com and From Name Email? The email name is Wordpress, and the email is wordpress@website. I would like a custom email, I have configured it but wp_mail using that one

Comment: try to change wordpress admin email if it not works you can modify from email using this code. but you need to use email that related to your domain. :D :D

Answer (score 0):

I would advice you to do some research before you post your questions. Stack Overflow is not a replacement for a webdeveloper ;)

I'm unsure if the subscription start date stays unchanged, But that's something you could test.

[More info on the WC_Subscription class](https://woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/develop/functions/#section-3)

```
function send_custom_email($subscription)
{
    $start_date = $subscription->get_date('start');

    if (date('Y-m-d') === date('Y-m-d', strtotime($start_date))) {
        // Send the email.
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_subscription_payment_complete', 'send_custom_email');
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! I will test it. Do you know in // Send the email, how can I send the email to the user? Thank you!